# BigInt data type in SQL Server mapped as Text in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, sql-server

I have a table in a SQL Server 2008 database containing a BIGINT data column. When I tried to import it into ArcMap 10, it automatically converted as Text of 8 length. This caused the records that have a big integer longer than 8 fail to display. The ArcMap reported "The row contains bad value."

Could anyone help with any solution to this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think ArcMap respects the BIGINT field type.  I believe Double is your best bet, you'll just have to round to the nearest integer with a python script.

[ArcMap Field Types](ftp://ftp-fc.sc.egov.usda.gov/GIS/training/arcgis/tips-tricks/arcgis-data-types.pdf)